# Extract a column from a dataframe in R?

Tags: r

Lets say that I have a dataframe (resid) that looks like this:

```
                            [,1]
1970-01-02 01:00:00  9.958329261
1970-01-03 01:00:00 -4.219493148
1970-01-04 01:00:00  2.188976400
1970-01-05 01:00:00 -0.992230006
...
```

I would like to create a vector containing only the left side column. Is there a way for me to do this?

Comment: This is neither a statistical question nor about extracting columns. You can get the row names by the command "rownames".

Comment: You need to break up the column using 'grep' commands if you wish to extract the year, time, value into separate fields.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use (assuming your dataframe is called `df`):

```
times <- rownames(df)
```